# Splash screen is stretched in android ionic 6 Capacitor 4

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am trying to display a splash screen in ionic framework, I generated the resources with `cordova-res`, but when I run the app the splash screen is stretched, I tried everything but nothing works

Capacitor.config

```
SplashScreen: {
  launchShowDuration: 3000,
  launchAutoHide: true,
  backgroundColor: '#ffffffff',
  androidSplashResourceName: 'splash',
  androidScaleType: 'CENTER_CROP',
  showSpinner: false,
  splashFullScreen: false,
  splashImmersive: false,
}
```

Style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/splash</item>
</style>
```

I have searched the ionic forum but they never talk about a solution

Comment: Now I'm not working on that project but I solved the problem with the .9.png files, this is an editor included in Android Studio that allowed you to choose which part of your image will be stretched and which will not, with that the image will still remain stretched but the logo or the main part will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try changing `splashFullScreen` and `splashImmersive` to `true`.
2. In `config.xml` in root of the project put: `<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />`.
3. In `styles.xml` under `resources` put/change:

   ```
   <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
       <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
       <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
       <item name="android:background">@null</item>
   </style>

   <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
       <item name="android:background">@drawable/splash</item>
   </style>
   ```

Hopefully it will fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't work, I've tried many configurations and nothing changes

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Did you try editing the splashscreen in Android Studio itself?